# What is the relationship between relativistic momentum and kinetic energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, momentum, mass-energy

In classical physics: If momentum is doubled, KE increases by a factor of 4.

Classical:

$ \frac{1}{2} m(2v)^{2} = $

$ \frac{1}{2}4mv^{2} = $

$KE = 2mv^{2} $

In Modern Physics, that is not the case

Modern:
$E = \sqrt{p^{2}c^{2}-(m_{o}c^{2})^{2}}$

$KE_{rel} = E - (m_{o}c^{2})^{2}$

$KE_{rel}/KE_{classical}  \neq 1$

Hence, relativistic KE does not increase by a factor of 4.

*Information for anyone who had a similar question regarding the comparison between classical and modern Physic's interpretation of kinetic energy.

Comment: None of your relativistic equations are correct. They aren’t even dimensionally consistent.

Comment: I wish we could stop referring to relativity as 'Modern Physics'.  It's 115 years old!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In the relativistic limit the energy-momentum relationship of light $E=pc$, holds, and energy increases proportional to momentum, not proportional to momentum squared. In that limit the mass becomes irrelevant and all the energy is kinetic; indeed that this happens for all momentums light could have is a consequence of light’s masslessness.

At lower momentums you get scaling somewhere in the middle, twice the momentum is between 2 and 4 times the momentum.